# How to refresh the URI type data : insert into temptable values (SYS.URIFACTORY.getURI('URL'));

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, query, plsql

How to refresh the URI type  data and reload to table , whenever the website url got refresh.

My complete code:

```
   Created table with URI TYPE 

create table vignesh3(url URIType)

   loaded data from the url using geturi function.

INSERT INTO adw.vignesh3 VALUES
  (SYS.URIFACTORY.getURI('http://www.floatrates.com/daily/nzd.xml'));

Loading the columns as a table using xmltable option. 

select e.url.getXML() from adw.vignesh3 e

SELECT xt.*
FROM   adw.vignesh3 x,
       XMLTABLE('/channel/item'
         PASSING x.url.getXML()
         COLUMNS 
           title     VARCHAR2(100)  PATH 'title',
           link     VARCHAR2(100) PATH 'link',
           DESCRIPTION       varchar2(100)  PATH 'description',
           PUBDATE  varchar2(100)  PATH 'pubDate',
           BASECURRENCY varchar2(60) PATH 'baseCurrency',
           BASENAME  varchar2(60) PATH 'baseName',
           TARGETCURRENCY varchar2(60)  PATH 'targetCurrency',
           TARGETNAME  varchar2(60) PATH 'targetName',
           EXCHANGERATE  varchar2(60)  PATH 'exchangeRate',
           INVERSERATE  varchar2(60)  PATH 'inverseRate',
           INVERSEDESCRIPTION  varchar2(60)  PATH 'inverseDescription'           
         ) XT;
```

I need to refresh this data whenever the url updates the rates.

Comment: This is required to load currency rate to the temp table and required refresh of rates on hourly basis

Comment: Are you looking for [`DBMS_SCHEDULER`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_sched.htm#ARPLS72235)?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response - Yes looking for the schedule to refresh the data.